# Run a macro without having it set as last macro (@@)

Tags: macro

I have <kbd>@@</kbd> mapped to <kbd>Space</kbd>. This can be really convenient.

Sometimes I want to combine a macro with another. So maybe I need to record `q` as `@:/jump` to run my last regex substitution and move to the next place I probably want to run it. Then <kbd>@q</kbd> and press <kbd>Space</kbd> until I'm happy.

Unfortunately if you run <kbd>@q</kbd>, during the macro the <kbd>@@</kbd> repeat will be set to <kbd>@:</kbd>. Is there a way to run <kbd>@:</kbd> without setting it to <kbd>@@</kbd> while recording the macro for `q`?

In this toy example, instead of combining macros I could copy the substitution into a register and paste it during the `q` recording, but that requires more foresight, and a bit of fiddling.

Edit:

I guess as far as combining <kbd>@:</kbd> goes, I can always use `:%s/\v//gc...` There are situations I've wanted to combine macros that have nothing to do with regex though. Only option I can think of so far to do what I want is remap <kbd>Space</kbd> to always be <kbd>@q</kbd>, instead of the last macro, which might be okay since that's 80% of the time what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to run @: without setting it to @@ while recording the macro for q?

Yes:

For normal 'character' registers:

```
:call feedkeys(@a)
```

`":` needs special handling:

```
:call feedkeys(':' . @: . "\<CR>")
```

If you use this often, you may want to map it:

```
" for @:
:noremap @- :<C-u>call feedkeys(':' . @: . "<Bslash><lt>CR>")<CR>

" for normal char registers
:noremap @_ :<C-u>call feedkeys(@)<Left>

" more complex version of the latter, improved to not need a final <CR>
noremap @_ :<C-u>call FeedReg()<CR>
function! FeedReg()
  echo 'Enter register name character:'
  let reg=nr2char(getchar())
  call feedkeys(getreg(reg))
endfunction
```

Comment: A cookie for the right answer. Although before I read this, I realised that I have a keyboard with programmable layers, and have greedily made one of the layers my macro layer, where every letter is mapped to @ and the letter. For me being on that layer and hitting asd or whatever is as and perhaps more convenient. I like your @- @_ though, that's a nice extension to existing finger memory.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to run @: without setting it to @@ while recording the macro for q?

Yes:

```
:<C-p><CR>
```

(or equivalently

```
:<Up><CR>
```

.)